# OpenEdge SQL Statement Cache - per server or per connection?

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

Is anyone able to confirm if the the SQL statement cache exists per SQL server or per connection.

The following states that is is per server:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P37596

The following states that it is per connection:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P25743

Comment: Execution plan cache is at server level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is per connection.

The kbase entries do not actually conflict with each other -- they are saying that the parameters are specified per server.  So you could setup different servers with different parameters.  But the caches being configured are per connection as influenced by the server that the connection is associated with.

Comment: Thank you Tom, for my sanity's sake are you able to confirm that the Statement Cache detailed in the above links is the same as the Client Database-Request Statement Cache referenced here: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P150383  . Much appreciated

Comment: No, the client statement cache is a different thing altogether.  These kbase entries refer to tuning SQL servers.  The cleint statement cache applies to both 4gl and SQL and it is used for debugging purposes.

Comment: For info on the client statement cache: http://pugchallenge.org/downloads2014/2392_whats_going_on_v14.pdf